# Migrating Apache POI 3.14 to 3.17 and JDK9:

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-poi, java-9

I struggle migrating some of my projects from apache poi 3.14 to the latest 3.17 and i can't find further informations on the apache website.

It seems like some Classes / Packages have been removed, in my cases:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFont;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
```

All result in "... cannot be resolved" since switching the librarys from 3.14 to 3.17 (having all 3 jars poi, poi-ooxml and poi-ooxml-schemas in the classpath).

So i guess i have to rewrite / adpot huge parts of my code but i can't find any hints on which classes or functions to use instead in the current lib.

Edit:
Additional Screenshots of the Errors (even after a Project Clearn + Rebuild):

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

Edit2:
Further tests have shown that as soon as the project uses JDK9 over JDK7 the named classes can no longer be imported / accessed. No matter which version of the library i use (3.14 or 3.17).
So this must be related to the JDK9. What can i do to fix this?

Comment: did you rebuild the project?

Comment: rebuild the project and share the error it's showing to you, if any still...

Comment: Did a full Project clean + rebuild. Will add Screenshots in the original Post.

Comment: Can you post the maven dependencies / added libraries? Only it looks like you've forgotten to include at least one key jar

Comment: The Classpath consists of:

- commons-codec-1.11
- commons-io-2.6
- commons-lang3-3.7
- commons-logging-1.2
- dom4j-2.1.0
- httpclient-4.5.5
- httpcore-4.4.9
- log4j-api-2.10.0
- log4j-core-2.10.0
- metadata-extractor-2.10.0
- ojdbc7
- poi-3.17
- poi-ooxml-3.17
- poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17
- swingx-all-1.6.5-1
- vecmath-1.5.2
- xmlbeans-2.6.0
- xmpcore-6.1.8

Comment: I should note that those libs in the classpath are exactly the same as before. Only difference is that the poi libs were updated from 3.14 to 3.17. So i doubt that I simply miss a required jar (as long as 3.17 didnt add a new dependency compared to 3.14).
Running on Eclipse 4.7.2 and JDK 9.0.4.

Comment: Additional info: when i restart Eclipse the displayed error message on the imports says "... is not accessible" instead of "cannot be resolved":

"The type org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle is not accessible" 

Cleaning and rebuilding results in the "... cannot be resolved" message again. Can this be related to JDK9?

Comment: Going back to JDK7 resolved the import errors with v3.17 (leaving only the deprecated / removed functions which was expected).
So it is definitly related to JDK9 resulting in some parts of the library becomming inaccessible. What can i do?

Comment: Can you try to build it with JDK7, move all dependencies into a directory and launch it from there with JDK9?

Comment: Compiling against JDK7 and executing with JDK9 ist not a problem (that actually works). But it would prevent me from using the JDK9 specific APIs like the new Taskbar Features.
But i finally found a solution for my problem (will write an separate answer post).

Answer (score 1):

Finally nailed it down:

The issues are not (directly) caused by the lib and/or jdk9 itself but by Eclipse (v4.7.2).

I have 2 Classes in my project using the apache poi library to read or write Excel files.
One Class is the one that I took the screenshots of the issues from. 
The second class had 0 errors in eclipse (funny because it imports the same poi classes...).

But the truth was that the second class had 2 errors, too! 
These errors were caused by the update from v3.14 to 3.17 because of API changes but they where somewhat obfuscated / not visible in Eclipse.

After I fixed those 2 errors in the second class all the Import errors ("...cannot be resolved" and "... not accessible") disappeared in the primary class and the code becomes compilable and runable again (even with JDK9).

I only found out about the real cause by tinkering around on the command line trying to compile the stuff by hand... So yeah. I hope this helps others with simmilar issues :).

Comment: I am a bit confused by how you mean you fixed the errors. What exactly were the 2 errors and what did you do to fix them?

Comment: It is an eclipse bug. There was nothing to fix because the code was fine (can be compiled on command line for example).
Have already a ticket open @eclipse bugzilla concerning this matter.

Comment: Sadly not sure how to fix it on my end. 99% sure we had the same issue, but your explanation isn't really clear on what steps I could take to resolve this issue. I am seeing that I have all my dependencies and no errors occur. The only problem I have is it can't detect any of my classes at all.

Comment: See here for more Details: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=531117

And double check that you do not use any removed Apache POI functions in your code (in case you migrated from an earlier version of the LIB). See the Apache POI Changelog for migration Details (which Classes / Enums / etc moved where) and adjust your code.
After I did that the code was compile- and runable again but eclipse keeps showing strange errors -> see my link above to the eclipse bug ticket.
Looks like 4.8 in june will fix this. Maybe 4.7.3 in march.

Comment: so it turns out mine was down to a compilation error and Maven refused to update the failed packages. Couldn't even detect they existed. This did help me determine I wasn't exactly seeing the same thing! Thanks so much for following up with me.